# Datamapper not performing the right query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamapper

I am trying to perform a simple query, but Datamapper does not seem to be returning the right result sets.

This seems so basic that there is no reason why it is wrong.

I think it is probably a syntax issue.

```
class User
 has n, :answers
 property :id, Serial
 property :name, String
end

class Answer
 belongs_to :user
 has n, :topics, :through => Resource
 property :id, Serial
 property :text, Text
end

class Topic
 has n, :answers, :through => Resource
 property :name, String, :key => true
end

o=User.create(:name=>'tom')
puts a=Answer.create(:user=>o, :text => 'a1', :topics => [
 Topic.first_or_create(:name => 'aboutme'),
 Topic.first_or_create(:name => '@onetom')
])

#THIS WORKS
#puts Answer.all(:user => {:name => 'tom'}, :topics => [{:name => 'aboutme'}])

#THIS DOES NOT WORK
#puts o.answers.all(:topics => [{:name => 'aboutme'}])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using correct parameters, if you want to add conditions on associations you should use the dot notation. I made an example script for you here:

https://gist.github.com/709867

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of there being a bug in the relationships code (it looks like you're using the nested attributes plugin?)

One nice thing about DataMapper is that you can check what query is being generated.  Just tag ".query" onto the end of any collection and you'll get the query object out.

`Answer.all(:user=>{:name=>'tom'}, :topics => [{:name => 'aboutme'}]).query` in this case.

You can also see what SQL the query would generate by doing the following:

```
q = Answer.all(:user=>{:name=>'tom'}, :topics => [{:name => 'aboutme'}]).query
DataMapper.repository.adapter.send(:select_statement, q)
```

Give that a shot and post back about whether it's doing something strange or not (or even post the query objects being generated and i can take a look).